# gawk error with 3GB file on Win server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, gawk

**Background**: I'm trying to load a 3GB csv text file (20M rows x 46 col) into a SQLite table. The data import fails with error: “record 3,493,675 had only 2 fields when table expecting 46 values”. i want to find out if that record has only has 2 fields (corrupted) or if problem elsewhere (my suspicion).

So I tried to look at the ‘offending' record using gawk:

**gawk -F, "NF<46 {print FNR,$1,NF}"**

but got an error message (on server running Windows 2008 with 8 procs, 16GB RAM | i do not have admin privileges):

**“grow_top_buffer: iop->buf: can’t allocate 1,073,741,826 bytes of memory (not enough space)”.**

i googled this error, saw some posts from 2003 about a bug, but did not get solution.

**So, here’s the problem**: I have the same data file on my 4GB RAM Win 7 laptop and same version of gawk works fine – it reads entire 20M records … and all 20M record in the file have the 46 fields required for the table.

I tried several different gawk statements but all failed on server - all work on my PC.

Question: why the buffer memory error with gawk on the Win server?

thanks, peter

Comment: If the file has Unix line feeds, an AWK implementation on DOS might read it all as a single line.

Comment: @user1405306 This is very interesting. Did you confirm that the file on the laptop was identical to the server file? Maybe with a checksum or `FC`? Or at least compare filesizes in bytes? Did you ever discover the cause? The only reasons I can imagine it would want 1GB memory is if it didn't find the Record Separators, or there was something off with the file encoding, or the locale of your server is different from your laptop. Did the file have only ASCII data?

Answer (score 2):

If the server machine is running a 32-bit version of Windows and your PC runs a 64-bit version of Windows, gawk might be able to allocate more (virtual) memory on your PC than on the server.  This is because it might not be able to address that amount of memory on the server.

Regarding your problem, awk should not need a lot of memory to process the file in the way you want.  This seems to me like a gawk bug.  Try another version of awk, like Kernighan's [One True Awk](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/)

Comment: thanks, i believe the server hardware is 64-bit - not sure about the win server 2008 software. the pc is 64-bit h/w and s/w.